# TCP checksum calculator

Tags: tcp, wireshark, checksum

I am facing a problem with TCP and I suspect that the checksum calculated by Wireshark for TCP is not right, so I would need something which allows me to calculate the checksum for the packets captured. Is there something to do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/).

Load the packets from your pcap file

```
packets = rdpcap("tst.pcap")
```

Select one packet

```
packet = packets[0]
```

Select the TCP segment

```
tcpSegment = packet[TCP]
```

Read the stored checksum

```
hex(tcpSegment.chksum)
```

Then to compute the checksum, delete the stored checksum

```
del tcpSegment.chksum
```

And show the new computed checksum

```
tcpSegment.show2()
```